# Scraping content from website using Beaufifulsoup and Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

UPDATE = My script extracts the following text, but I am still struggling to get just the information I need.

```
[<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-nmd-cs2-pk-ba7189.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-nmd-cs2-pk-w-ba7212.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-nmd-r2-pk-w-ba7560.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-ultraboost-x-bb0879.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/books-all-gone-book-2016.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/converse-ctas-modern-hi-156645c.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/converse-ctas-modern-hi-156646c.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/new-balance-m576-lifestyle-m576-pgw.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-jordan-13-retro-low-310810-407.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-jordan-4-retro-308497-117.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/puma-clyde-cny-fm-363637-01.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/puma-creeper-white-black-364462-01.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/puma-creeper-wrinkled-patent-364465-01.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/reebok-zoku-runner-ultk-is-bd5852.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/staple-fila-solid-pique-polo-1702p3795-blk.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/staple-fila-camo-poly-jkt-170203584-camo.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-eqt-support-adv-bb2791.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-eqt-support-adv-pk-ba7496.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-equipment-support-ultra-ba7474.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/adidas-nmd-r2-pk-bb2910.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/asics-gel-kayano-trainer-knit-h7s4n-4545.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-jordan-13-retro-414571-122.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-jordan-15-retro-881429-400.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-jordan-6-retro-384664-113.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-max-woven-boot-921854-002.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-max-woven-boot-921854-001.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-air-sock-racer-og-875837-001.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/nike-nikelab-air-max-1-pinnacle-859554-400.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/puma-clyde-premium-core-362632-03.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/reebok-cl-lthr-golden-neutrals-bd3744.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/reebok-club-c-85-gum-bs7635.html')" title="Shop Now" type="button"><span><span>Shop Now</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy51cmJhbmp1bmdsZXN0b3JlLmNvbS9pdC8,/product/10356/form_key/Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd/')" title="SHOP NOW" type="button"><span><span>SHOP NOW</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy51cmJhbmp1bmdsZXN0b3JlLmNvbS9pdC8,/product/10346/form_key/Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd/')" title="SHOP NOW" type="button"><span><span>SHOP NOW</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy51cmJhbmp1bmdsZXN0b3JlLmNvbS9pdC8,/product/10341/form_key/Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd/')" title="SHOP NOW" type="button"><span><span>SHOP NOW</span></span></button>, <button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy51cmJhbmp1bmdsZXN0b3JlLmNvbS9pdC8,/product/10336/form_key/Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd/')" title="SHOP NOW" type="button"><span><span>SHOP NOW</span></span></button>]
```

I am currently trying to extract the "form_key" information from the scraped text. In this example the form key is "Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd" -  and this is the text I would like to extract and print

Can you please advise me how to extract and print the information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to get `Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd` from the element in your example?

Comment: Yes mate, if you load the page and view source it is located in the same place every time.

Comment: Will you post all of your code up to getting this button? I don't want to duplicate work, but I think I can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, this code searches for the buttons in the page, picks one, gets the `onclick` attribute, then gets the form key. The regex was used from Robert's answer, so be sure to thank him with an upvote!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

req = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
response = BeautifulSoup(req.content,
                         "html.parser")

all_buttons = response.find_all("button", title="SHOP NOW") 

one_button = all_buttons[0]

onclick_attribute = one_button['onclick']  # this gets the text of the onclick attribute

def get_form_key_from_onclick_attr(attr_text):
    """ use a regex to extract the form key from the onclick attribute text """
    results = re.search('.*/form_key/([^/]+)/.*', attr_text)
    return results.group(1)

get_form_key_from_onclick_attr(onclick_attribute)
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks, this is amazing so much simpler than the method I was using before. This is so eye opening for me, I can not thank you enough

Comment: No problem! Happy I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the `form_key` using regular expressions:

```
In [1]: s = 'http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy51cmJhbmp1bmdsZXN0b3JlLmNvbS9pdC8,/product/10356/form_key/Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd/'

In [2]: import re

In [3]: m = re.search('.*/form_key/([^/]+)/.*', s)

In [4]: m.group(1)
Out[4]: 'Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd'
```

Therefore, to match your example, you can do the following:

```
import re

s = """onclick="setLocation('http://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy51cmJhbmp1bmdsZXN0b3JlLmNvbS9pdC8,/product/10356/form_key/Ayxpa0t2JpTEfPBd/')"><span><span>SHOP NOW</span></span></button>"""
m = re.search('.*/form_key/([^/]+)/.*', s)

if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Comment: I am looking to find it in the source page

Comment: The string you provided, is that within the page source?

Comment: yes, if you search "form_key" you will see where it is located

Comment: Does my example work? I'm sorry, but I'm not willing to click and search the source code of a site that I've never heard of. Nor do I think anybody else is willing to click on the link.

Comment: No sorry, it is just a sneaker site. I'm really struggling to get soup to just extract what I need. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for helping!! This is such a better method than I was using.